# Compiling VLC met undefined reference error

Tags: vlc

I tried to compile vlc on a ubuntu docker container.

```
(In host)
git clone --depth=1 vlc
docker run -v ~/vlc:/root/vlc -it ubuntu:17.04 

(In container)
# install dependencies
apt update && apt upgrade
apt install git build-essential pkg-config libtool automake autopoint gettext
apt-get build-dep vlc

# install ffmpeg
cd /root
git clone --depth=1 https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg.git
cd FFmpeg
./configure
make
make install

# build vlc
cd /root/vlc
./configure --disable-wayland --disable-chromecast
make
```

Then this error

```
make[4]: Entering directory '/root/vlc/modules'
  CCLD     libavio_plugin.la
/usr/local/lib/libavutil.a(hwcontext_vaapi.o): In function `vaapi_device_free':
/root/FFmpeg/libavutil/hwcontext_vaapi.c:899: undefined reference to `XCloseDisplay'
....
```

I barely knows C. It seems that it has some problem with XCB, how do I proceed?

Comment: Do you need to have source & compiled objects available from the FFMpeg library? I'd verify what your dependencies are...